# JINT - Unable to "console.log"

Tags: c#, jint

I am new to `JINT`, and trying to just do some basic tests to kind of learn the ropes. My first attempt was to just store some javascript in my database, load it, and execute it in a unit test. So that looks essentially like this....

```
[Fact]
public void can_use_jint_engine() {
    using (var database = DocumentStore()) {
        using (var session = database.OpenSession()) {
            var source = session.Load<Statistic>("statistics/1");

            // join the list of strings into a single script
            var script = String.Join("\n", source.Scripting);

            // this will create the script
            // console.log("this is a test from jint.");
            // 
            var engine = new Jint.Engine();
            // attempt to execute the script
            engine.Execute(script);
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work, I get this error, which makes absolutely no sense to me, and I cannot find any documentation on.

> Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptExceptionconsole is not defined    at
>   Jint.Engine.Execute(Program program)    at
>   Jint.Engine.Execute(String source)    at
>   SampleProject.Installers.Instanced.__testing_installer.can_use_jint_engine()
>   in _testing_installer.cs: line 318

Can anyone assist in shedding some light on this? I'm pretty confused at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With JavaScript there are three entities - we care about. The host (browser, your application etc), the engine (JINT in this case) and the script ("`console.log(...)`") in this case.

JavaScript defines a bunch of functions and object as part of the language, but console is not one of them. By convention, browsers define a console object that can be used in the manner you describe. However, since your app is not a browser (and JINT does not do this by itself), there's no console object defined in your namespace (globals).

What you need to do is add a `console` object that will be accessible in JINT. You can find how to do this in the docs, but here's a simple example of how to add a log **function** to the engine so it can be used from the JS code (example taken from github).

```
var engine = new Engine()
        .SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine))
        ;

    engine.Execute(@"
      function hello() { 
        log('Hello World');
      };

      hello();
    ");
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an anonymous function, instead of giving it the name `hello`? And if so, how would that be achieved? Like ... `function() { log('Hello World'); };` - can that even be done? Or does every function __have__ to be given an explicit name?

Comment: You can just have the script you have in your example, but w/o the console.. i.e.: engine.Execute(@"
        log('Hello World');
    ");

Comment: Well, I mean - I want to store the whole function in the database, but it needs to be wrapped in function brackets - but the "name" isn't going to be known at design time, so I wanted to use anonymous functions. So I'm still confused about that.

Comment: Oh sweet! I got it! I have to do it with the extra `()`. So it looks like ... `(function() { /* code */ })();`, and then I can just call execute on the joined lines!!! PERFECT!